# Error on starting new activity(android)

Tags: java, android, xml

Yesterday I made simple app; So, when I press button, the new activity(Activity2Main) should start.
Yesterday it was working and I was happy. Everything was great.
Today, I've tried to run app and what did I see? I saw crash and close app message, when I press the button.
What can it be?
Here's log from console:

```
E / AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.dns.politicalscience, PID: 2076
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {
        com.example.dns.politicalscience / com.example.dns.politicalscience.Main2Activity
    }: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line # 2: Error inflating class < unknown >
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread. - wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 616)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line # 2: Error inflating class < unknown >
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java: 539)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java: 423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java: 374)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java: 267)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java: 129)
at com.example.dns.politicalscience.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java: 11)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java: 6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java: 1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread. - wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 616)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java: 645)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java: 58)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java: 694)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java: 762)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java: 704)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java: 492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java: 423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java: 374)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java: 267)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java: 129)
at com.example.dns.politicalscience.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java: 11)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java: 6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java: 1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread. - wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 616)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java: 619)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java: 58)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java: 694)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java: 762)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java: 704)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java: 492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java: 423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java: 374)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java: 267)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java: 129)
at com.example.dns.politicalscience.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java: 11)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java: 6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java: 1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread. - wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 616)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 44728332 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 9 MB until OOM
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java: 609)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java: 444)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java: 1080)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java: 2635)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java: 2540)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java: 870)
at android.view.View. < init > (View.java: 3948)
at android.view.ViewGroup. < init > (ViewGroup.java: 573)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout. < init > (RelativeLayout.java: 248)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout. < init > (RelativeLayout.java: 244)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout. < init > (RelativeLayout.java: 240)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java: 619)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java: 58)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java: 694)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java: 762)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java: 704)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java: 492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java: 423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java: 374)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java: 267)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java: 129)
at com.example.dns.politicalscience.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java: 11)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java: 6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java: 1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread. - wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 616)
```

My Manifest.xml-file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"></activity>
</application>
```

and here's my activity1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/canbe_backgroud"
    tools:context="com.example.dns.politicalscience.MainActivity"
    android:onClick="onClickBackground">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="55mm"
        android:layout_height="20mm"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:background="@drawable/start_button"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClickObama"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="55mm"
        android:layout_height="20mm"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/idea_button"

        android:clickable="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="55mm"
        android:layout_height="20mm"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:background="@drawable/about_botton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClickAbout" />
</RelativeLayout>

Here's second activityxml:

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/canbe_backgroud"
        tools:context="com.example.dns.politicalscience.Main2Activity">

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I've found no bugs in my code, even in java
Here's java-code onClick in first ativity:

```
 public void onClickAbout(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And that is the second one:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
}
```

}

What happened, guys? Yesterday it worked good on emulator, but today it shows crash message.

Comment: If you examine the stack trace in detail you see `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 44728332 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 9MB until OOM`  -- Does that help?

Comment: So, the promlem is, because my emulator has no memory, right?

Comment: It would seem you are trying to allocate a 44MB object with only 4MB free.

Comment: What should I do to fix that problem with memory?

Comment: Figure out why you're trying to send a 44MB object graph, then don't do that.

Comment: That's interesting bug, cause there are no graphic object or another objects with such big size. Also, there are ony pictures in png oh(

Comment: I didn't say graphic. An object graph is a root object and all its transitive dependencies, i.e. all the objects it refers to, all the objects _they_ refer to, etc.  This is how object serialization/deserialization works.

Comment: There is something going on with the BitmapFactory. Check the sizes of the images you are working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase the size of memory allocated to the emulator...

Here is a way to find the options to manipulate heapsize for emulator from Andriod studio 1.2.0

1. Menu Tools->Android->AVD Manager
2. edit the virtual device of choice
3. click advanced settings and scroll down

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As comments point out, its an OutOfMemoryError.

Try using largeHeap in yout manifest file.

```
<Application
..............
android:largeHeap="true"
............../>
```

Anyway, its caused by some large bitmap you are trying to load, check your resources.

Answer (score 0):

As the others mentioned and as your logcat shows, you run out of memory. Your drawables used in the image buttons are too large (or together are allocating large amounts of memory).

First, try to compress the images with an Image editor from your pc. Then overwrite the old images with the new compressed images.

Then, make sure that if you are running it on a virtual machine, follow the steps that @Randhawa said.

After these things, do the following:

Load your bitmap efficiently as described here (in the section "Load a Scaled Down Version into Memory"):http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap

Then convert the bitmap to drawable like this:

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
```

And set your image buttons background programmatically like this inside onCreate after setContent (of your activity's xml):

```
ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton); 
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
 if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){ 
    imgButton.setBackgroundDrawable(d); 
// where d is your Drawable 
} 
else{
 imgButton.setBackground(d);
 }
```

Do the same thing for image button 2 and 3.